# How to get all values from session which start with certain key

Tags: php, laravel, session

As the title, I want to get all values from session which start with certain value.

For example, I'm counting post views in my project and I'm storing them on session. Then I want to reach all stored viewed values on session..

```
Session::put("views.".$post->id);
```

How can I get all stored views ?

is there any way to do it something like below ?

```
Session::get("views.*");
```

Comment: there is no way to do this you may store the whole array as an session data

Answer (score 1):

You can use collection's filter method as below:

```
$session = collect(session()->all())->filter(function($value){
        if (!is_string($value))
            return false;
        return strpos($value, 'views.') === 0;
    })->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

I just realize that, when we use "." (dots) when we seperate the keys, laravel puts them in different arrays (I mean creating multi dimensional array) So I'm able to reach all values using just parent key.

```
Session::get("views");
```